# Why does my boolean modifier sometimes work and sometimes not? (trying to create holes)

Tags: modifiers

[Link to video showing my problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/ou7fgb/why_does_my_boolean_modifier_sometimes_work_and/)

I didn't do anything different with the other cuts that worked, yet this specific cut I want to make won't work. Also when I move the cylinder that is in the blue spot significantly far from where it is positioned, the modifier works...So it seems to be a problem with its position? [image: The red ones worked, the blue one is not working]

The blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DxvdBxbOws-22B1_QmihJBY_WL4yAR9y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add at least some screen shots showing examples that do and don't work so we can have some idea of which of the many possible problems you are facing.  If you can add a blend file showing both working and not working cases that would be even more useful. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: I added a link that shows this.

Comment: Hi. Link-only answers are discouraged, if the link goes down so 
does the answer. Please help us making this site a real 
knowledgebase and add all relevant steps to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, sorry for being selfish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of bad topology at this spot. There are actually bad 3 verts. The two bad verts on the right are very close together but not close enough that *Merge by Distance* works. They are hard to select even with box selection:

[image: 3 bad verts]

You can merge them manually (<kbd>M</kbd>, *First/Last/Center*), and move the remaining vert out of the way with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. Then the *Boolean* modifier works as expected:

[image: fixed topology]

If the vert is too close to the boolean object then the result is flipped again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why but it looks like booleans work better with closed objects, so extrude and close it, boolean, then delete the faces you've created:

[image]

[image]